# Snake-like alignment in css

Tags: css

I have been struggling with the following problem in CSS. I have an arbitrary number of items (spans or divs) that I want to wrap inside a container in a snake-like pattern.

What I mean by this is that if I have 10 items, which are each 20px wide, I would like them to display as follow in a 60px wide container:

```
0 1 2
5 4 3
6 7 8
    9
```

I have tried using flexbox in CSS, but I can only get the items to display like this:

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9
```

If that can help, I know the exact width of the individual items, but I do not know the width of the container.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you use any html structure?

Comment: While a CSS guru may be able to provide you with a pure CSS solution, I'd just like to preemptively ask if you'd be open to a javascript or jQuery solution? You could group each block of three elements into a row, and using `odd` and `even` in CSS, float the row's children to opposite sides.

Comment: Please post the HTML you are planning to use.

Comment: The alternative I considered is to have an HTML grid (with each row/column pair possessing a unique ID) and to dynamically assign the items to its right place using javascript, but that's less elegant than a CSS solution if it exists... I might have to resort to that though.

Comment: Is the container going to be fixed at 60px wide?

Comment: @Dre As I wrote in the OP, the width of the container is not known.

Comment: Sorry, didn't spot that. So to clarify: as the items are fixed at 20px, you'll have three columns in a 60px container, 4 columns in an 80px container etc. Or do you want to always have three columns, and scale the items as the container gets larger?

Comment: To be honest, i don't think that JS solution can be 'less elegant' than CSS solution (if any) in this case...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you create your HTML structure with `parent` - `rows` - `items` you can use `flex-direction: row-reverse` on `.row:nth-child(2n)` elements and that will create desired result.

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row:nth-child(2n) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
.row:nth-child(2n):last-child .item {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, better than my solution :)

Comment: Better than mine too... +1

Comment: This would be the perfect solution if I knew how many items there would be per line, and how many lines there would be... But I guess this something that I can only figure out in JS anyway, so I'm going to accept the answer. Thank you so much for your very quick response!

Comment: Don't you want 3 items per line ?

Comment: Items per line is variable - it depends on container width...so, i guess JS is mandatory in this case. P.S. OP mentioned different HTML structure, without strictly defined rows in HTML...with defined rows - it is much easier.

Comment: @Andreq Not sure if this will help you but if you are generating items you can use js to wrap items in rows on some specific number of items https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1344/

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing your markup limitations, you could use the following structure and `float` values to make it work.

```css
.ltr, .rtl {
  width: 60px;
}
.ltr div, .rtl div {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.rtl div {
  float: right;
}
.ltr div {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="ltr">
  <div>0</div><div>1</div><div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="rtl">
  <div>3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div>
</div>
<div class="ltr">
  <div>6</div><div>7</div><div>8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the css `direction: rtl;`

demo here: http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/YpjGKK

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <span>1</span>
    <span>2</span>
    <span>3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row2">
    <span>4</span>
    <span>5</span>
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <span>7</span>
    <span>8</span>
    <span>9</span>
  </div>

</div>

.row2 {
  direction: rtl;
  float:left;
}

.row {
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use flex method

```js
function add(){
  var item = document.createElement('div')
  item.className = "item"
  item.style.setProperty("--i", list.children.length + 1)
  item.textContent = list.children.length + 1
  list.append(item)
  item.scrollIntoView()
}
function del() {
  list.querySelector('.item:last-child').remove()
}
```

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: aliceblue;
}
.list{
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.item{
  width: calc( (100% - 30px) / 4 );
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: royalblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  order: var(--i);
  filter: hue-rotate(calc(var(--i) * 10deg));
}
.item:nth-child(8n + 5){
  order: calc(var(--i) + 3)
}
.item:nth-child(8n + 6){
  order: calc(var(--i) + 1)
}
.item:nth-child(8n + 7){
  order: calc(var(--i) - 1)
}
.item:nth-child(8n + 8){
  order: calc(var(--i) - 3)
}
.item:nth-child(8n + 5):last-child,
.item:nth-child(8n + 6):last-child,
.item:nth-child(8n + 7):last-child{
  margin-left: auto;
}
.action{
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list" id="list">
  <div class="item" style="--i: 1">1</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 2">2</div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 3">3</div>
</div>
<div class="action">
  <button onclick="add()">增加</button>
  <button onclick="del()">减少</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/xboxyan/pen/jOQgZbX

use grid method

```js
function add(){
  var item = document.createElement('div')
  item.className = "item"
  item.style.setProperty("--i", list.children.length + 1)
  list.append(item)
  item.scrollIntoView()
}
function del() {
  list.querySelector('.item:last-child').remove()
}
```

```css
html,body{
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  /* justify-content: center; */
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: aliceblue;
}

.list{
  display: grid;
  width: 300px;
  gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  counter-reset: count;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
}

.item{
  counter-increment: count;
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  background: royalblue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  filter: hue-rotate(calc(var(--i) * 10deg));
  
  &::before {
    content: counter(count);
  }
  
  &:nth-child(8n + 5){
    grid-column-end: -1;
  }
  
  &:nth-child(8n + 6){
    grid-column-end: -2;
  }
  
  &:nth-child(8n + 7){
    grid-column-end: -3;
  }
  
  &:nth-child(8n + 8){
    grid-column-end: -4;
  }
}
.action{
  margin-top: 20px;
}

/*增加适量CSS*/
```

```html
<div class="list" id="list">
  <div class="item" style="--i: 1"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 2"></div>
  <div class="item" style="--i: 3"></div>
</div>
<div class="action">
  <button onclick="add()">增加</button>
  <button onclick="del()">减少</button>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/wheatup/pen/GRwVwdV/fce68f6eb87f3aefa5d6ff9886194529