# Display bootstrap grid in mobile view in snake pattern

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to arrange bootstrap grid in snake like pattern on mobile view of my web page. Currently my grid is in the pattern as follow as:-

```
1  2 
3  4
```

on my web page

and in mobile view

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want it as

```
1
2
4
3
```

and so on.. What should be done for such kind of arrangement?

```
<div class="col-sm-8">This is Grid Cell 1

<div class="col-sm-4">This is Grid Cell 2


<div class="col-sm-4">This is Grid Cell 3

<div class="col-sm-8">This is Grid Cell 4
```

Comment: You might get an idea from this user who posted a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064753/snake-like-alignment-in-css but you could add bootstrap flex as well: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snake-like alignment in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064753/snake-like-alignment-in-css)